# Reuse connection from socket created by the OpenSSH client

Tags: go, ssh

OpenSSH client has a feature called "ControlMaster" that allows to reuse connections between multiple ssh sessions over a single network connection.

I was wondering if it was possible using `x/crypto/ssh` package of Golang to reuse a connection from a socket that has been created by the OpenSSH client with a command like:

`ssh -M -f -N -o ControlPath=$HOME/.ssh/shared.sock myUsername@targetServerName`

Is there any way to create a Golang Client from this `$HOME/.ssh/shared.sock` socket?

We usually use the `Dial` function to create the Client.

`func Dial(network, addr string, config *ClientConfig) (*Client, error)`

But I see there is as well the `NewClient` function that seems to be for reusing an existing connection.

`func NewClient(c Conn, chans <-chan NewChannel, reqs <-chan *Request) *Client`

I struggle to understand how I can instantiate the `Conn` and the two channels in a proper way.

Maybe it is not doable at all?

The aim is to be able to implement a kind of wrapper of the OpenSSH client and trigger commands using Golang before/after calling the actual OpenSSH client process. It would as well avoid having to reimplement the target host/port logic and the authentication.